# Angular 2 and native Promises

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having issue using native promises with second angular and typescript:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    public user = {};

    constructor( private authService:AuthenticationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    login() {

        console.log( 'Connecting to server' );

        this.authService.login( this.user ).then(( response ) => {

            // works
            console.log( response['success'] );

            // error
            console.log( response.success ); 

        }, ( error ) => {

            console.log( error );
        });
    }
}
```

below is simple service, with fake connect to the server:

```
export class AuthenticationService {

    // ... some code ...

    login( loginData ) {

        let self = this;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            // fake delay - for now is no back end
            setTimeout(function() {

                if ( loginData.username === 'username' && loginData.password === 'password' ) {

                    resolve({
                        message: "Successfully logged in",
                        success: true,
                        errors: null
                    });
                } else {

                    reject({
                        message: "Wrong user data reperesented",
                        success: false,
                        errors: {
                            "username": true,
                            "password": true
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    // ... some code ...
}
```

Tried to search what I have to do to solve `Property 'success' does not exist on type '{}'.` error but without success.

Comment: sounds like typescript hitting you. what does your authService.login look like?

Comment: *Who* is giving you that error *when*?

Comment: @DanielA.White I updated my question with service example.

Comment: you should annotate the `return new Promise` line. also its odd that you have a `success` flag in the promise.

Comment: @deceze angular-cli then compiling from typescript

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't know if I understand you correct, but I tried: `this.authService.login( this.user ).then(( response: any ) => {` and it worked, so now I'm conffused which way is correct.

Comment: @GomatoX, do you get the error during runtime or during compilation time? Is the error reported by a typescript compiler or a browser?

Comment: @Maximus browser.

Comment: Did you try to replace your `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){` by `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: @Karbos it's no big difference `function(){}` old style and `() => {}` is new ( es6 ) style.

Comment: Yes but it mays solve some problems with your this and passing old style functions as argument

Comment: And switching `response['success']` after  `response.success` ?

Comment: @GomatoX, how does the compiled code look? Add it to your question

Comment: @Karbos so it's a problem, that `response.success` is not working, but `response['success']` is working, and why it's I can't find an answer.

@Maximus I'm sorry, but browser throws error because angular-cli compiles, not exact code, but `throw new Error("long message..." )`

Comment: @GomatoX, show compiled code

Comment: @Maximus here you go: http://pastebin.com/jEicrmYS

Comment: @GomatoX, there is no code from your question there, just try searching for `authService` for example

Comment: @Maximus so as I mentioned: `but browser throws error because angular-cli compiles, not exact code, but throw new Error("long message..." )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132517/discussion-between-gomatox-and-maximus).

Comment: @GomatoX, sorry, but I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the code above is not typed.

To make this work it should be either

```
login( loginData ): Promise<any> { ... }
```

or

```
this.authService.login( this.user ).then(( response: any ) => { ... })
```

A better way is to make types work for you instead of ignoring them:

```
interface IAuthLoginResponse {
    message: string;
    success: boolean;
    errors: any;
}

...

login( loginData ): Promise<IAuthLoginResponse> {
  return new Promise<IAuthLoginResponse>(function (resolve, reject) { ... })
}
```